# return of an function is LPVOID or better a pointer to a list

Tags: c++

i am using c++ to develope an extension for a tool we are using. from the api of the tool i call a function, which returns a LPVOID. from the documentation i know it is a list of pairs(int 16bit, int 32bit).

i know created a local pointer to this list with :

```
list<pair<INT16, INT32>> * ptrList = (list<pair<INT16, INT32>>*) functionToGetList();
```

now my question is how can i iterate trough the list?

```
std::list<pair<INT16, INT32>>::iterator * it;
for (it = *ptrList .begin(); it != ptrList .end(); it++) {

}
```

i tried something like this but just got the error call, that it has to be a class.

can someone pls help me with my problem?

with kind regards

Comment: `LPVOID` is not a part of C++ standard. What API/library are you using. Please, add suitable tags.

Comment: `ptrList` is a pointer to a `std::list`, you need to dereference it as such. And remember that the dereference operator `*` has lower [operatoir precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the structure select operator `.`. Perhaps you should think about what the "arrow" operator `->` does...

Comment: Please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Welcome to SO.

Comment: *from the documentation i know it is a list of pairs* -- So why didn't the library simply return that instead of a void pointer?

Comment: Regarding your library and your casting... Whenever you need to do a C-style cast, there's something wrong. In this case it seems the library is badly designed and implemented. I would recommend you try to find another one providing the same or similar functionality, or at least kick the author of the library in the back.

Comment: thanks to ur hints guys. specialy the "arrow" hint was quite well. for the calls to change the API there is no opportunity to change it because the extension is running inside the basic tool so its the only viable API to use.

Comment: @MarcusStelzer -- The problem of assuming that the type is a `std::list` (even though you say it's documented), you are tightly coupling your code with the library's implementation.  If the author decides to change to another container type to return, your program will then be broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto const& item : *ptrList)
    std::cout << item.first << ',' << item.second << '\n';
```